# nginx + uwsgi custom 502 will not work

Tags: django, nginx

Hi I am trying to get a custom 502 page working on a website and can't seem to get it working.

Basically the way i'm testing it is I'm just stopping uwsgi and accessing the page and every time i get the default nginx 502 page. Can someone please explain to me how to get this working? I've been at this for over a week with 0 success. I have a file named 502.html in public_html and i can access it directly with http://ask.ploy.io/502.html but as soon as i stop uwsgi and try to access the main domain http://ask.ploy.io I get the default 502 page. Here is the vhost config:

```
### nginx vhost conf for ployio
server {
listen 80;
server_name ask.ploy.io www.ask.ploy.io;

access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/ask.ploy.io main;
error_log /home/ployio/access-logs/ask.ploy.io debug;

root /home/ployio/public_html;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

location /502.html {
root   /home/ployio/public_html;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location / {
    error_page 404 403 = @uwsgi;
    log_not_found  off;
    error_page   502  /502.html;
    root   /home/ployio/public_html;

}

location @uwsgi {
    internal;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ployio/.uwsgi/uwsgi.sock;
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/uwsgi_params;
}

location ~* ^.*\.php$ {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        return 404;
    }
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass  http://204.61.223.114:8888;
}

location /cpanel {
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://cpanel.ask.ploy.io:2083/$1 permanent;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If 502 it's the only error code you want to handle with a custom error page, you just need to be specific in the location:

```
location /502.html {
    root   /home/ployio/public_html;
}
```

Your current location is only being matched with the exact "/50x.html" path, which indeed does not exists in your server: http://ask.ploy.io/50x.html

It's also possible using nginx variables ($uri or something similar) to redirect all 50x errors to that root directory, but for your needs this should be enough.

Comment: O.k so I changed it to look like this...    `root /home/ployio/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /502.html;
    location /502.html {
    root   /home/ployio/public_html;
    }`

Comment: Try being more specific in error_page directive too. Use `error_page 502 /502.hml`. Also is possible that your original nginx configuration will work if you rename your 502.html file to 50x.html.

Comment: O.k so edited my main comment to show what I have changed.  I have tried all kinds of variations of this and i still can't get it to work.  Thanks for you help in this matter so far.  I really don't get why this isn't working it should be straight forward.

Comment: Try to paste the error log of your nginx when trying to open http://ask.ploy.io/ Maybe we can find out something useful there.

Comment: O.k so i re-edited my initial post to match exactly what changes i've made to my vhost. So one weird thing i noticed is my access log file and error log file are identical yet in the vhost they are clearly specified. So in my error_log file i see... 2012/04/01 13:46:43 [error] 20089#0: *4132 connect() to unix:/home/ployio/.uwsgi/uwsgi.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 24.200.194.125, server: ask.ploy.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/ployio/.uwsgi/uwsgi.sock:", host: "ask.ploy.io" This is odd to me looks like more of an acces

Comment: Try deleting the error_page directive in the `location /502.html`.

Comment: I removed the lines you mentioned and also updated orginal post to show my changes. Still getting the same default 502 page.

Comment: It's possible that the way you're redirecting to the WSGI location (via 404 and 403 errors) is by-passing the 502 error page configuration in that location and nginx is giving its default 502 page. Did you try to put the error_page directive in @uwsgi location?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is in the `location @uwsgi` section.. it never seems to handle the 502 return correctly.. maybe by design?

This is a working config

```
server {
   listen 80;
    server_name ask.ploy.io www.ask.ploy.io;

    access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/ask.ploy.io main;
    error_log /home/ployio/access-logs/ask.ploy.io debug;

    root /home/ployio/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ployio/.uwsgi/uwsgi.sock;
        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/uwsgi_params;
    }

    error_page 502 503 504 @maintenance;
    location @maintenance {
        root /home/ployio/public_html_502;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /502.html break;
    }

}
```

Make sure you put the 502.html in a new root and reference it there.. ps.. randall sucks

Comment: "randall sucks" is completely unnecessary